My code is not able to open the app after i write into the tag
I am creating an app using flutter to read and write into NFC tags using nfcmanager package. In the process in a stuck in the part where i want write into the tag so that it can open the app that i built (the app that i built to write into NFC tag). Please someone who has the experience in this area please look at the code and let me know what am i doing wrong in the code. when i write into the tag form using nfcwriter to open the app i bulit it works perfectly.

import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nfc_manager/nfc_manager.dart';

class NFCNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
bool \_isProcessing = false;
String \_message = "";

bool get isProcessing =\> \_isProcessing;
String get message =\> \_message;

Future\<void\> startNFCOperation(
{required NFCOperation nfcOperation,
String dataType = "",
String inputValue = ""}) async {
try {
\_isProcessing = true;
notifyListeners();

      bool isAvail = await NfcManager.instance.isAvailable();
    
      if (isAvail) {
        if (nfcOperation == NFCOperation.read) {
          _message = "Scan Now";
        } else if (nfcOperation == NFCOperation.write) {
          _message = "Writing to Tag";
        }
        notifyListeners();
        NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag nfcTag) async {
          if (nfcOperation == NFCOperation.read) {
            await readFromTag(tag: nfcTag);
            notifyListeners();
          } else if (nfcOperation == NFCOperation.write) {
            await writeToTag(
                nfcTag: nfcTag, dataType: dataType, inputValue: inputValue);
          }
          _isProcessing = false;
          notifyListeners();
          await NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
        }, onError: (e) async {
          _isProcessing = false;
          _message = e.toString();
          notifyListeners();
        });
      } else {
        _isProcessing = false;
        _message = "Please Enable NFC";
        notifyListeners();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      _isProcessing = false;
      _message = e.toString();
      notifyListeners();
    }
}

//To read the tag
Future\<void\> readFromTag({required NfcTag tag}) async {
Map\<String, dynamic\> nfcData = {
'nfca': tag.data\['nfca'\],
'mifareultralight': tag.data\['mifareultralight'\],
'ndef': tag.data\['ndef'\]
};
print(nfcData);

    String? decodedText;
    if (nfcData.containsKey('ndef')) {
      List<int> payload =
          nfcData['ndef']['cachedMessage']?['records']?[0]['payload'];
      print(payload);
      decodedText = String.fromCharCodes(payload);
      print(decodedText);
    }
    
    _message = await decodedText ?? "No data found";
    //print(_message);

}

//To write into tag
Future\<void\> writeToTag(
{required NfcTag nfcTag,
required String dataType,
required String inputValue}) async {
NdefMessage message =
\_createNdefMessage(dataType: dataType, inputValue: inputValue);
await Ndef.from(nfcTag)?.write(message);
\_message = "Done";
}

NdefMessage \_createNdefMessage(
{required String dataType, required String inputValue}) {
switch (dataType) {
case 'ANY':
{
return NdefMessage(\[NdefRecord.createText(inputValue)\]);
}
case 'APP':
{
return NdefMessage(\[
NdefRecord.createExternal('android.com', 'apk',
Uint8List.fromList('com.google.android.keep'.codeUnits))
\]);
}
case 'URL':
{
return NdefMessage(\[
NdefRecord.createUri(Uri.parse('https://keep.google.com')),
\]);
}
case 'Mail':
{
return NdefMessage(\[
NdefRecord.createUri(Uri.parse("mailto:ayushstha151@gmail.com")),
\]);
}
case 'Contact':
{
String contactData =
'BEGIN:VCARD\\nVERSION:2.1\\nN:Ayush Shrestha\\nTEL:+9779857684555\\nEND:VCARD';
Uint8List contactBytes = utf8.encode(contactData);

          return NdefMessage([
            NdefRecord.createMime(
              'text/vcard',
              contactBytes,
            ),
          ]);
        }
    
      default:
        return const NdefMessage([]);
    }

}
}
enum NFCOperation { read, write }

